# Objective-C - How to fit page in WebView

Tags: macos, webview

I need to know how can i fit a page in WebView? In iOS there is `webView.scalesPageToFit=YES`, but in OS X development? How can i do?? Is possible?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The method of UIWebView sizeToFit is helpful :)

Comment: You specifically asked for the OS X answer but answered with an iOS answer.